# Spring Cloud Function in Azure throws IllegalStateException upon triggering

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-functions

After running azure-functions:run target with mvn, I trigger the Azure Function on the endpoint:

> hello: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/hello

In the logs it is shown that Spring starts up and I get the following error, and I cannot wrap my head around the cause of it:

```
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.253Z] Handler processing a request for: hello
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z] Executed 'Functions.hello' (Failed, Id=403ee5e4-464b-4d0a-bd56-d6ade21d2de8, Duration=1103ms)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.hello. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z] Exception: IllegalStateException: No function defined
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z] Stack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaMethodInvokeInfo.invoke(JavaMethodInvokeInfo.java:22)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.execute(EnhancedJavaMethodExecutorImpl.java:55)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.broker.JavaFunctionBroker.invokeMethod(JavaFunctionBroker.java:57)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:33)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.InvocationRequestHandler.execute(InvocationRequestHandler.java:10)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.handler.MessageHandler.handle(MessageHandler.java:45)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at com.microsoft.azure.functions.worker.JavaWorkerClient$StreamingMessagePeer.lambda$onNext$0(JavaWorkerClient.java:92)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No function defined
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.AzureSpringBootRequestHandler.handleRequest(AzureSpringBootRequestHandler.java:99)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at com.dropware.function.HelloHandler.execute(HelloHandler.java:28)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  ... 16 more
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No function defined
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.AzureSpringBootRequestHandler.handleRequest(AzureSpringBootRequestHandler.java:99)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.AzureSpringBootRequestHandler.handleRequest(AzureSpringBootRequestHandler.java:83)
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z]  ... 17 more
[2020-11-10T10:56:35.272Z] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No function defined
```

I have two domain classes:

```java
public class Greeting {

    public Greeting() {
    }

    public Greeting(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

```java
public class User {

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The function is HTTP-triggered and it follows exactly the example provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/getting-started-with-spring-cloud-function-in-azure)

```java
public class HelloHandler extends AzureSpringBootRequestHandler<User, Greeting> {

    @FunctionName("hello")
    public HttpResponseMessage execute(
            @HttpTrigger(name = "request", methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
                    authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) HttpRequestMessage<Optional<User>> request,
            ExecutionContext context) {

        context.getLogger().info("Greeting user name: " + request.getBody().get().getName());
        return request
                .createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(handleRequest(request.getBody().get(), context))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();
    }
}
```

The entry-point for Spring is as straight-forward as it gets.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<User, Greeting> hello() {
        return user -> new Greeting("Welcome, " + user.getName());
    }
}
```

The dependencies from the pom.xml file are:

```
    org.junit.jupiter
    junit-jupiter
    5.4.2
        
    org.mockito</groupId>
    mockito-core
    2.23.4

    org.springframework.boot
    spring-boot-starter-test
    2.3.5.RELEASE

    com.microsoft.azure.functions
    azure-functions-java-library
    1.3.1

    org.springframework.cloud
    spring-cloud-function-adapter-azure
    3.0.11.RELEASE
        
    org.springframework.cloud
    spring-cloud-function-web
    3.0.11.RELEASE
        
    org.springframework.boot
    spring-boot-starter-jdbc
    2.3.5.RELEASE
        
    org.springframework.boot
    spring-boot-devtools
    2.3.5.RELEASE
       
    org.springframework.boot
    spring-boot-configuration-processor
    2.3.4.RELEASE
        
    mysql
    mysql-connector-java
    8.0.22
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer below pom.xml and make sure if you are not missing any of the fields and app settings.

```
    <property>
      <name>WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE</name>
      <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
      <value>~3</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME</name>
      <value>java</value>
    </property>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try to provide function name, if there are multiple fucntion need to be executed aa follows
```

```
@Bean("hello")
    public Function<User, Greeting> hello() {
        return user -> new Greeting("Welcome, " + user.getName());
    }

@Bean("GoodMorning")
    public Function<User, Greeting> goodMorning() {
        return user -> new Greeting("Good Morning " + user.getName());
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.